# How do I control the styling of an html unordered list?

Tags: css, cross-browser, styling

Who thought that styling a list of links could be so troublesome!

- First issue I would like to use an
  arbitrary char as the bullet. I am
  sure now that this is impossible but
  maybe you know different?
- In any case I would like to control the distance between the bullet and the contents of the <li>.
- I would like to control the height of the bullet (so it stays centered to the text in the <li> irrespective of fonts/sizes etc).
- I would like the bullet to stay within the <div> that contains the <ul> rather than hang out the side.
- I would like long items in a <li> to wrap around leaving the bullet clear of the text.

I want it to work in all browsers above IE6. with as little special pleading for IE's weirdnesses as possible! (this means I cannot use `:before`)

I am tempted to use <span> and </br> rather than lists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you use a remove the paddings/margins of the list element using CSS so you will have a clean slate for all browsers.  Then, if you always want the bullet image to be centered, use an image.

```
 ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

ul li{
  padding: 0 0 0 20px; /*so text does not appear on top of bullet */
  background: url(error.gif) no-repeat 0 50%; /* this will set the bullet to appear in the middle */
}
```

Comment: I agree. The best way is to use a background image, trying to style the dots themselves is just too hard.

Answer (score 3):

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/

Answer (score 1):

For an unordered list, you will have to make a graphic to display an arbitrary character. The other available values are:

```
list-style-type: disc | circle | square | none
```

To make the bullet stay within the text instead of hanging out, use

```
list-style-position: inside
```

??? Not sure what you mean about "wrap around" in your last point.